# COCOA: Migrating from third party zlib to libz.dylib

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I am working on a project which uses third party `zlib` to compress data in gzip format. My requirement is to discontinue third party zlib which compile with source code and use `libz.dylib`. version of Third party zlib used in my project is 1.4.4 which sourcee has classes named `Compreess2.cpp`(), `gzio.c` etc and my project uses function of theses classes but  at `/usr/include/`location i see only `zconf.h` `zlib.h`. Is there any tutorial to use `libz.dylib`.

Comment: Actually you don't need `Compress2.cpp` and `gzio.c`. Just add libz.dylib in frameworks. That's odd that you have just two files in include. There is should be much more h-files. How you added libz.dylib?

Comment: @Cy-4AH in include I have only files related to zlib other .h files are also present. I added libz.dylib under link binaries with libraries section of build phase tab in Xcode.